# PyQt: Multiple Buttons Same Variable

Tags: python, pyqt

I have a window with 18 buttons (1 to 18) and I want it to print out the button text when clicked. However, it only prints the text if I click the 18th button. How can I print the text when buttons 1-17 are clicked? Thank you.

```
class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(self)
        x = 0
        for i in range(0, 6):
            for k in range(0, 3):
                x = x + 1
                self.PrimaryCombo = QPushButton(str(x))
                self.grid.addWidget(self.PrimaryCombo, k, i, 1, 1)

        self.PrimaryCombo.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)

    def buttonClick(self):
        print (self.PrimaryCombo.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FormWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    # ...
    for i in range(0, 6):
        for k in range(0, 3):
            x = x + 1
            button = QPushButton(str(x))
            button.clicked.connect(self.buttonClick)
            self.grid.addWidget(button, k, i, 1, 1)

def buttonClick(self):
    print (self.sender().text())
```